# JSP dynamic text

Tags: spring, jsp, iframe

I'm using Spring 3 to design a website. On one part of the website, you can search id's. However, id's are not unique and may return multiple records. To create a unique key, we use a timestamp associated with that id

When a user does a lookup for an id and there are multiple results, the site displays a radio selection of timestamps to allow the user to choose their record.

What I want to do is display the information from the record on the page. However, due to the possibility of multiple records, this display needs to be able to change whenever the user selects a radio button.

Is this possible? Can I change the text on the page without forcing a reload?

The other option I'm considering is embedding the information in an iframe and having that reload within the search page. However, I'm running into issues sending the information to that page for display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.
You will need to use JavaScript.
You can either display one record and hide the the rest, displaying the correct record based on selected radio button or load only the chosen record using AJAX.

For example, if you want to update HTML using AJAX you could do the following with the help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) framework:

```
$.get( "ajax/getdata", function( data ) {
          $("#needstextchange").text(data.text);
});
```

*get* is a jQuery method which does AJAX GET call to the server.

There are several assumptions here:

1. Data is returned in JSON format (it is very easy to do in Spring MVC)
2. ajax/getdata is mapped to the method which returns the data
3. The jsp page has an element with id needstextchange.

Comment: how would I change the html text using AJAX?